# How to check form validation inside directive applied to itself?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

With AngularJS, I'm trying to check validity of a form within a custom directive.

In the template:

```
<form name="formName" custom-directive="someController.function()">
...
</form>
```

In JavaScript:

```
angular.module("myApp")
    .directive("customDirective", function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

                var callbackFn = attrs.customDirective;

                // Check form validation, then call callbackFn
                scope.$eval(callbackFn);
            }
        };
    }
);
```

Usually, we can see form validation with `scope.formName.$valid`, but the form's name can be different, so I need a generic way to access it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add [`require: 'form'`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-require-) directive:

```
.directive("customDirective", function () {
    return {
        require: 'form',
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, formController) {

            var callbackFn = attrs.customDirective;

            // Check form validation, then call callbackFn
            if (formController.$valid) {
                scope.$eval(callbackFn);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

After that form controller will be injected as fourth argument into link function, and you would be able to check form validity with `formController.$valid` property.